# Setting log level for inner class (in Glassfish)

Tags: java, logging, glassfish

I'm looking for a way to set the log level for an inner class, let's say I have the following class:

```
package mypackage;

class Outer {
   Inner inner = new Inner();

   public void logSomething() {
       Logger.getLogger(Outer.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, "I'm alive!");
       inner.logSomething();
   } 

   class Inner {
       public void logSomething() {
           Logger.getLogger(Inner.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, "I'm alive too!");
       }
   }
}
```

I can set the log level of Outer using the name `mypackage.Outer`. But how do I set it for `Inner`? I have tested the following without success:

- `mypackage.Outer`
- `mypackage.Outer.Inner`
- `mypackage.Outer$Inner` (gives an error)
- `mypackage.Inner`

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: for reference: It works for me using `mypackage.Outer$Inner` (slf4j v1.7.5 + slf4j-log4j12). log4j related bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41487 
But be aware that `mypackage.Outer$Inner` won't be considered as a child logger of `mypackage.Outer` ... so configuration won't be inherited :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Inner.class.getName()` is returning `mypackage.Outer$Inner` which doesn't follow the expected convention for [Logger.getLogger()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29) parameter

> `name` - A name for the logger. **This should be a dot-separated name** and should normally be based on the package name or class name of the subsystem, such as java.net or javax.swing

You can explicitly use

```
Logger.getLogger("myPackage.Outer.Inner").log(Level.FINE, "I'm alive too!")
```

and set the level using `myPackage.Outer.Inner`

Curiously enough, the message gets formatted by `SimpleFormatter()` using $ for inner class as it's outputting class name, not logger name

```
28-feb-2013 19:04:16 mypackage.Outer$Inner logSomething
FINE: I'm alive too!
```

Comment: Is there a way to set just that in log4j.properties? I'm failing bigtime. The inner class is protected though, might be it.

Comment: `Logger.getLogger("myPackage.Outer.Inner")` did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: So that's for JUL which is what the code seems to be coding against. It doesn't apply to logback, where `myPackage.Outer$Inner` is correct in the config xml, and `LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggingClass.getName());` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Inner.class.[getCanonicalName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName--) is returning mypackage.Outer.Inner . So you can use

```
Logger.getLogger(Inner.class.getCanonicalName()).log(Level.FINE, "I'm alive too!")
```